# How to run custom commands during `make uninstall` from qmake in QT5?

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qt5, qmake

I have a QT project that installs a service to the system, when running `make install`. The relevant parts of the `.pro` file are the following:

```
init.path = /etc/init.d/
init.files = myservicename

updaterc.path = /etc/init.d/
updaterc.extra = chmod 755 $$init.files; \
                 update-rc.d $$init.files defaults 97 03; \
                 service $$init.files start

INSTALLS += target ... init updaterc
```

This installs the service correctly and then starts it.

However, when I run `make uninstall`, although the installed files are correctly deleted, the service remains installed and running. I would like the service to be stopped and uninstalled when running `make uninstall`.

The commands for stopping and uninstalling the service are the following:

```
sudo service myservicename stop
sudo update-rc.d -f myservicename remove
```

But I cannot figure out how to integrate the above commands in `.pro` file, so that `qmake` can understand them and create the relevant rules in the Makefile.

The only documentation I have found on the subject is this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html, but it does not say anything about uninstalling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try to use .uninstall command.

```
mytarget2.path = ~/Documents/inst
mytarget2.target = test.txt
mytarget2.commands = @echo "custom command"
mytarget2.uninstall = @echo "uninstall" 
INSTALLS += mytarget2
```

it will generate this makefile:

```
   ####### Install

install_mytarget2: first FORCE
    @test -d $(INSTALL_ROOT)/Users/mac/Documents/inst || mkdir -p $(INSTALL_ROOT)/Users/mac/Documents/inst
    @echo custom command

uninstall_mytarget2: FORCE
    @echo uninstall
    -$(DEL_DIR) $(INSTALL_ROOT)/Users/mac/Documents/inst/ 


install:  install_mytarget2  FORCE

uninstall: uninstall_mytarget2   FORCE

FORCE:
```

Comment: Yes the `uninstall` command is helpful, and seems to solve the issue, I will wait until the end of the bounty in case anybody else has a better idea, otherwise the bounty is yours. Thank you very much for your help.